# nomad job failed to start docker

Tags: python, docker, nomad

I have a docker image which contains a simple web page. it works fine on its own:

```
docker run -p 747:747 <docker image name>
```

Also I wrote a nomad job to get the docker image and run it:

```
    job "example" {

  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type = "service"
  update {

    max_parallel = 1


    min_healthy_time = "10s"


    healthy_deadline = "3m"

    progress_deadline = "10m"

    auto_revert = false

    canary = 0
  }

  migrate {

    max_parallel = 1

    health_check = "checks"

    min_healthy_time = "10s"

    healthy_deadline = "5m"
  }


  group "web" {

    count = 1

    restart {
      # The number of attempts to run the job within the specified interval.
      attempts = 2
      interval = "30m"

      delay = "15s"

      mode = "fail"
    }

    ephemeral_disk {

      size = 300
    }


    task "redis" {

      driver = "docker"


      config {
        image = "mahdijalilvand/docker_web:latest"
        port_map {
          http = 747
        }
        command = "python"
        args = ["/app/app/app.py"]

      }

      resources {
        cpu    = 500 # 500 MHz
        memory = 1024 # 1024MB
        network {
          mbits = 10
          port "db" {}
        }
      }


      service {
        name = "redis-cache"
        tags = ["global", "cache"]
        port = "db"
        check {
          name     = "alive"
          type     = "tcp"
          interval = "10s"
          timeout  = "2s"
        }
      }


    }
  }
}
```

but I do not have any access to the web page.

Comment: So what is the error with you?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT the web page by "http://localhost:747" cannot be seen

Comment: If you do not run the command `docker run -p localhost:747:747 <docker image name>`, you should check who listen to the port 747.